# I want to get unique rows on joining tables

Tags: postgresql

I am running the following query while trying to join 3 tables :

```
select
  a.project_id, a.acc_name, a.project_name, a.iot,a.acc_id, a.active,
  b.app_fte, b.contact_person, c.cost_call_date
from
  Account a, Application b, account_version c
where
  a.acc_id in (Select acc_id from account where acc_name='GGG') and
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.cost_call_date) = 3;
```

Sample data from the tables are as follows :

```
 Account :
 acc_id  acc_name  iot  acc_contact  project_id  project_name  ilc_code  license_no  active
 2        GGG       NA    YYY         7777         HHH           TTR      766         false

 Application :
 app_id  app_name  app_fte  contact_person  acc_id
  1       sfsf       4       sdsdff          2

 Account_version :
 line_id  acc_id  version_no  chargable_fte  cost_call_date  is_approved
  9        2       7            4             2018-03-20
```

Here acc_id is the primary key for the Account table and the foreign key for the Application and Account_version tables. When I am running the above query I am getting 30 rows  I have also tried using the distinct keyword but still I get 10 rows. Please help me in getting unique rows.

Comment: You're getting 30 rows, then getting 10, that doesn't mean anything to us since we don't know how many you expect and why. And, unique across what values? All?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.project_id, a.acc_name, a.project_name, a.iot,a.acc_id, a.active, b.app_fte, b.contact_person, c.cost_call_date
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN Application b
    USING (acc_id)
INNER JOIN account_version c
    USING (acc_id)
WHERE a.acc_name = 'GGG'
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.cost_call_date) = 3
```

For reference as to why your query was giving you more rows than expected, try running this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM generate_series(1, 10) a, generate_series(1, 10) b
```

What you are doing by selecting from multiple tables as you did is a [cross join](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cross-join/). What you should actually be doing is an inner join to get the rows you want, and a DISTINCT if required to get only distinct rows from the results.